# API распознавания речи

Tags: node.js

Пишу бота для телеграмма на nodejs. Не могу найти api для speech-to-text с форматом ogg. Подскажите, если вы интересовались данной тематикой.

Answer (score 1):

Я плохо ознакомился документацией yandex speechkit. Данное API позволяет работать с .ogg кодека opus.